# MongoDB returning incorrect results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB 3.2 on Windows 10 and mongoose with Node.JS. For simplicity, I'm pasting mongo console query:

```
db.ethtransactions.find({
    "blockNumber" : 884629
})
```

Returns no results.

Expected:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5730dfa27549536802fb6da3"),
    "blockNumber" : 884629,
    "transactionIndex" : 27,
    "from" : "0xd005c515db902b1b77beb98370ba1f16b3111d7b",
    "to" : "0x5770345100a27b15f5b40bec86a701f888e8c601",
    "value" : "0"
}
```

If I add " to the "blockNumber":"884629" part, the query for blockNumber as follows:

```
db.ethtransactions.find({
    "blockNumber" : "884629"
    }
)
```

It returns the expected value in mongo console, but I returns the incorrect value from Node.JS.

Collection definition:

```
var ethTransactionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    blockNumber: Number,
    blockHash: String,
    hash: String,
    transactionIndex: Number,
    from: String,
    to: String,
    value: String,
    input: String,
    nonce: Number,
    gas: Number,
    gasUsed: Number,
    cumulativeGasUsed: Number,
    gasPrice: String,
    isContractCreation: Boolean,
    logsString: String,
    timestamp: Date
});

ethTransactionSchema.index({ blockNumber: -1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ hash: 1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ transactionIndex: -1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ to: 1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ blockNumber: 1, transactionIndex: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sometimes you use the blockNumber as a string and others as a number.

Comment: Sounds like `blockNumber` is a string in your actual document and not a number. The data types in your documents need to match how you define them in your schema.

Comment: If I do this db.ethtransactions.find( {blockNumber: {$type: 16}}) I get results, which should indicate that blockNumber is a Number.

Comment: The point is that it's a string in the particular document you're looking for.

Comment: I think you are right: > db.ethtransactions.find( {blockNumber: {$type: 2}}).count()
39879
> db.ethtransactions.find( {blockNumber: {$type: 16}}).count()
715646